# Time difference in php getting negative value at certain time intervals

Tags: php, mysql

```
$updateLog = "UPDATE `tablename` 
              SET `TotalTimeLoggedIn`= (
                SELECT TIMEDIFF( `LoggedOut` , `LoggedIn` ) ) 
              WHERE id = '$id'";
```

my logged in value is already stored and so is the logged out value at the time in start the above query

```
DateLoggedIn 2016-06-06 
LoggedIn 12:50:38   
DateLogged Out 2016-06-06
LoggedOut 04:36:57  
TotalTimeLoggedIn -08:13:41
```

It works for values like `11:20AM` to `11:50AM` but not `11:20 AM` to `12:15 PM` where i get negative valuse as well

Comment: save the time in 24 hours formate in database.

Comment: Your subquery is missing a `FROM` clause. I'm not sure why you need the subquery. It should just be `SET TotalTimeLoggedIn = TimeDIFF(LoggedOut, LoggedIn)`

Comment: You also need to handle the case where he logs out on a different day from login. If he logs in at `6/6 23:00` and logs out at `6/7 05:00`, you need to subtract the times and then add 24 hours.

Comment: Use a `DATETIME` field, not two separate fields, and avoid using AM/PM. The [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) should be used unless you have a very, very good reason. `DATEDIFF` will work correctly on valid `DATETIME` values.

Comment: I have the user automatically be logged off after 30 minutes.

Comment: maybe that's why I got a negative value. However, if I add a FROM clause it breaks the query

Answer (score 0):

`` TIMEDIFF( `LoggedOut`,`LoggedIn` ) ``, `TIMEDIFF()` returns 04:36:57 − 12:50:38 expressed as a time value. Which is equal to -08:13:41.

Your logged in time is 2016-06-06 12:50:38 and log out time is 2016-06-06 04:36:57. It seems log in is done after log out.(logout at 04.36 AM and login at 12.50 PM same day). This doesn't look correct according to 24 hour system.

If you still think its the difference between 12PM and 4PM try something like this,

```sql
IF(TIMEDIFF(`LoggedOut`,`LoggedIn`)<0,
  ADDTIME(TIMEDIFF(`LoggedOut`,`LoggedIn`),12:00:00),
  TIMEDIFF(`LoggedOut`,`LoggedIn`)
)
```

Comment: I dont think it can be that because I have two different pages for when I log in and when I log out My logout isn't updated until  the user clicks logout